# Cannot save symbol style in Mapinfo

Tags: mapinfo

I've read the User Guide, I've tried Google searches with every term I can think of, but I cannot figure out how to make MapInfo 11.5 save a new symbol style without saving a copy of the table! I've chosen my new symbol style (from the plain old MapInfo 3.0 Compatible set) in the Layer Display tab of Layer Properties and the map updates properly, but the Save Table option is not available. Neither is the Revert Table button, implying I haven't made any changes to the table at all. I don't understand!

How do I save a new symbol style for a table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hate to point out the obvious, but are you sure you are making changes to the layer, and not just doing a style override? Style Overrides only apply to the workspace and do exactly what they say on the tin, they override the layers style. To actually change the style you need to make sure the layer is editable, select all the objects in the layer and then change the style using the Symbol Style options, not the Style Override options.

If you are already doing this and are still coming up with the problem let us know exactly what you are doing, which buttons you are pressing (maybe with screenshots) so we can see where you might be going wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I usually open Esri Shapefiles and MapInfo asks you to choose one style for all objects in that file. I got stuck on thinking those styles couldn't be changed. I am now changing graphic styles to my heart's content.